# Azure API management automatically fetch when API is added in swagger

Tags: azure, api, azure-pipelines, azure-api-management

I have created azure API management and created API by importing swagger URL. Is there any possible way to update API operation when a new API operation is added or any modification is done in swagger every time?

Comment: Please refer [UPDATING SWAGGER](https://carldesouza.com/updating-swagger-in-an-azure-api-management-service/) and [Automatic Update of API in Azure](https://medium.com/@raswinraaj/automatic-update-of-api-in-azure-api-management-using-terraform-d761dbea9f91)

Comment: Was the given links helpful ?